# Sublime text 2 auto wrapping

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I am wondering that I saw in a tutorial video the tutor types .classname in sublimetext 2 and pressing tab it will appear like  and form.formclass[roll="form"] and it will become

```
 <form action="#" class="formclass" role="form">.
```

How could it possible? anyone help me?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are wanting to happen after typing a classname and pressing enter, you don't mention the form part at all. Is it a text expansion? Maybe something like Emmet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably saw was [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) for sublime text.

This provides many cool features when writing html or css. You can read more about these from the github repo I linked.

Answer (score 1):

That's snippets you can create to suits your needs, [here the doc](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) and [here some examples](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-code-snippets/)
Or there are pre-created snippets you can install using control panels, [here a list](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/snippet)